# Faster way to run long PDO insert statement?

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

So I am starting to switch over all my of mysql/php work database queries and such over to PDO.  I was wondering if the following method could be shortened somehow.  This particular example, is using a large registration form and inserting the results into the database.  I feel this is a lot more code than is necessary... Is there a shorter method to insert this into the database?

```
$query = $affiliates->prepare('INSERT INTO affiliates (afid, afTitle, afbio, afLink, afEmail, afAddress, afCity, afState, afZip, afphone, affacebook, aflinkedin, aftwitter, afPassword, afLon, afType, aftime, afApproved) VALUES (?, ?, ? , ? , ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,?, ?)');
echo "prepare successfull";

$query-> execute(array('',$afTitle, $afBio, $afLink, $afEmail, $afAddress, $afCity, $afState, $afZip, $afPhone, $afFacebook, $afLinkedIn, $afTwitter, $afPassword, '', $afType, $date, $afApproved))or die(print_r($affiliates->errorInfo(), true));
echo "Insert worked!";
```

I apologize for any bad structure, as I said, learning as I go.  Also will this protect against sql injection?

Thank you!

Comment: You could lose the `echo`'s and `or die()`'s, but thats about as compact as it gets. Take if from someone who has dealt with changing table-declarations: you DO want to name each column explicitly. Of course, any field that gets set to it's _default_ value you can skip.

Comment: Lose the columns that you aren't supplying values to. There are also wrappers for PDO in the various frameworks that will allow you to send an associative array of names to values in one call and create the actual SQL for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I wasn't sure.  @Cfreak so if I am NOT inserting data as in the first field for my example '' I do not need to include that in the sql, I assume I just skip it?

Comment: @Zanrok - If you do not specify the value for a field then the default will result upon insert. It looks like afid might be a column that you have set with auto_increment? If that is the case, then you certainly do not need to be attempting to set the value to ''.

Comment: @ghbarratt yup.  Thanks a bunch, still a lot of code but at least I can take some out. =/

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to put those column names and values into an array. Then, instead of listing out all the variables/columns multiple times, you can just use the array. For example, you could change your code to look like this:

```
$inserting = array();
foreach(array('afTitle','afbio','afLink','afEmail','afAddress','afCity','afState','afZip','afphone','affacebook','aflinkedin','aftwitter','afPassword','afType','aftime','afApproved') as $i) $inserting[$i] = ${$i};

$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO affiliates ('.implode(',', array_keys($inserting)).') VALUES ('.str_pad('', count($inserting)*2-1, '?,').')');
$sth->execute(array_values($inserting)) or die(print_r($sth->errorInfo(), true));
```

If you like this approach you might consider populating the array in a different way and possibly forego the creation of so many individual variables.

Comment: thanks again! I will probably stick to the code I have for now, as it is a little less confusing for me.  But thank you for your suggestion I might try and tinker with an idea like that later.